# Clojure: Reading CSV file and passing column values to curl

Tags: curl, clojure

New clojure user here. . . getting a bit tangled.

Project goals:

- read data from csv file
- isolate values in column 4
- pass values to html parameter
- use dynamically-created url in curl call

I'm getting stuck in two specific areas:

1) if I take out the println in process-files I start getting errors about it not knowing what to do with the '%' (Unable to resolve symbol: % in this context)

2) in call-curl I can't seem to get the passed-in id value into the id parameter of the URL.

```
(defn call-curl [id]
  (let [url "-d id=%s&format=pdf&cpull=1"]
    (shell/sh "curl" "-u" "username:password" "http://wwwin-search.com/protected-cgi-bin/office2pdf.cgi" (format url id))))

(defn process-files
   "Take file name and read data"
   [file]
   (let [data (slurp file)
         rows (rest (c/parse-csv data))]
     (dorun
     (map #(println (call-curl (nth % 3 nil))) rows))))

(process-files "output.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the first issue occurs because the code without `println` looked like:

```
(map (call-curl (nth % 3 nil)) rows)
```

Instead of:

```
(map #(call-curl (nth % 3 nil)) rows)
```

In cases when you want to travese the whole sequence just for side effects, I would suggest [`doseq`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/doseq):

```
(doseq [row rows]
  (call-curl (nth row 3 nil)))
```

Alternatively you can use [`run!`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/run!):

```
(run! call-curl (map #(nth % 3 nil)))
```

but I would argue that `doseq` version is more readable.

For the second issue, I think you need to provide each separate argument to `curl` invocation as a separate string: it should be

`"-d" "..."`

instead of

`"-d ..."`

I have refactored it a bit to make it more readable:

```
(defn call-curl [id]
  (let [data (format "id=%s&format=pdf&cpull=1" id)]
    (shell/sh "curl" "-u" "username:password" "-d" data "http://wwwin-search.com/protected-cgi-bin/office2pdf.cgi")))
```

One more remark that according to your code you are not passing the parameter in the URL but rather data passed as request body. From `man curl`:

> -d, --data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has
>   filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will  cause
>   curl
>                     to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Compare to -F,
>   --form.
>
> -d,  --data  is  the same as --data-ascii. --data-raw is almost the same but does not have a special interpretation of the @ character. To post data purely binary, you
>   should instead use the --data-
>                     binary option.  To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.

I wasn't sure why you did want to call `curl` instead of calling HTTP endpoints directly from Clojure but now when you commented that you indeed wanted to do it directly, let me recommend you to use [clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) library for that purpose. With its help it becomes as easy as:

```
(require '[clj-http.client :as http])

(defn call-url [id]
  (http/post "http://wwwin-search.com/protected-cgi-bin/office2pdf.cgi"
    {:basic-auth ["username" "password"]
     :form-params {:id id
                   :format "pdf"
                   :cpull 1}}))
```

Comment: Thank you! The suggestions resolved all the errors I am getting. The strange thing, and the reason why I am trying curl here, is if I make the call to the cgi from either clojure or java code, nothing happens. If I copy/paste the curl call into the command like, it works. But even using curl in this context the cgi script still does not kick off.

Comment: @Kawili-wili I have included an example how to execute HTTP POST using clj-http library.

Comment: Yes, much cleaner for sure. Thanks for that. I did try an uglier version of http.client straight away, but it seemed to do nothing, so I switch to trying curl. I just discovered that my problem was that I needed to use threading with the call-url function -- it was hanging on one call. I wrapped the function with future and now it is sailing like gangbusters. Thank you very much again!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

Uses `str` rather than `format`, dispensing to some extent with the desire for the let block:

```
(shell/sh
   "curl" "-u" "username:password" "http://wwwin-search.com/protected-cgi-bin/office2pdf.cgi"
   "-d" (str "id=" id "&format=pdf&cpull=1"))
```

Returns the output from call-curl using the `:out` keyword:

```
#((call-curl (nth % 3 nil)) :out)
```

Revised Code:

```
(require '[clojure.java.shell :as shell])
(defn call-curl [id]
  (shell/sh
   "curl" "-u" "username:password" "http://wwwin-search.com/protected-cgi-bin/office2pdf.cgi"
   "-d" (str "id=" id "&format=pdf&cpull=1")))

(defn process-files
  "Take file name and read data"
  [file]
  (let [data (slurp file)
        rows (rest (c/parse-csv data))]
    (dorun
     (map #(do (prn %) (call-curl (nth % 3 nil)))
          rows))))

(process-files "output.csv")
```

Comment: These are all great suggestion too. Thank you for taking the time to provide an alternate approach!